# Count number of items in a group Pandas Dataframe

Tags: pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

In the image below, I would like to group by 'ID' and count the number of 'Non_Id' in that group and make that a new dataframe. For example, ID 123 and 141 both have 3 Non_Ids.[image]

Comment: Assuming your DataFrame is named `df`: `df.groupby('ID')['Non_Id'].count()`. If you need unique count, `df.groupby('ID')['Non_Id'].nunique()`

Comment: That works, Thanks. Really appreciate your help.